# Do you have to delete your save file to start over again?

Tags: playstation-vr, no-heroes-allowed

My wife and I play on the same account.
I started it.
I gave up on it.
She deleted my save file in order to start anew.
She finished it and inspired me to do the same.
Now I want to start afresh.

(I think there is a non-VR game with this title. We have [the VR game](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA08016_00-NOHEROESALLOWED0).)